# Careers Zip Codes missing

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

My town, Highgate, Vermont (05459) doesn't exist in the Careers database of zip codes. No problem, it's a small place. But it doesn't show ANY jobs within a hundred miles, while a town 15 miles away (Grand Isle, 05458) shows 8 jobs.
[image: 05459 - Highgate]

[image: 05458 - Grand Isle]

Some further checking yielded 05450 (Enosburgh Falls, Vermont, which is the largest town in its area) and 05452 (Essex Jct., which is sizable city). 05453, the other Zip for Essex does work though.

Typing in town names works as expected.

[image: 05453 - Working Essex]
[image: 05452 - Essex, VT]

<sup><sub>Migrated from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300319/careers-zip-codes-missing</sub></sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed this now. Sometimes when we were looking up the geographical location of zip codes, we weren't recognising them as being specific enough - we were effectively treating them as large areas. This meant we only looked for jobs there were literally inside that area, and we were ignoring the distance.

In this case, we have no jobs at all in the exact zip code of 05459, so we were showing zero results.

The underlying problem is fixed and I've cleared out our cached geographical data for the zip codes mentioned in this post, so these searches are now showing the correct results. There will probably be some other zip codes affected by this, and these will drop out of the cache eventually over time, or if you report them then we can fix them manually.